# communicate javascript with python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

Well, I have a web site created with HTML and javascript. I want that this web page stores some data entered by the visitors in a form to a text file in the web server where the web page is located. My web server only supports python and perl scripting languages and for "sentimental" reasons I don't wish to change to another web server.

The code in the client side it's more or less clear for me, it would use javascript with AJAX xmlhttp class to post the data to the server but I don't know how to compose a python script that reads the received data, processes it and stores it in a text file. Can anyone please post some sample code?

I've already spend some days searching info but I get lost with what I read because often require to install something called frameworks. But as the web server supports python shouldn't this already be installed in the remote server and isn't it as simple as uploading a `myScript.py` in the web server?

Comment: You don't necessarily need a framework for something simple like that. An obsolete, but still widely-supported technology called CGI lets you write server-side web scripts in pure python. Google for "python cgi" there are tons of docs and tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If your web-server supports only CGI then write simple CGI script.
Doc for getting raw post from the reqquest: http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module
Thread where someone is putting together something looking like a code needed by you: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/42058-cgi-getting-raw-post-data